# Make sure bad patterns don't come back after refactoring

Tags: c, static-analysis

I'm refactoring an old C code. The code has absolutely no layered architecture (everything is being accessed by everything) and I'm trying to change that.

I would like to cut direct access to structure members (at least write for now) and only allow access through access functions. Is there some tool (or perhaps directly the compiler) that could check this rule for me?

I need this since I'm maintaining a fork and the upstream isn't very concerned with code quality.

Comment: rename the structure, and all compile errors are the direct accesses. :)

Comment: Are you willing to cause the code to break, and use that as an indication to draw your attention that the bad pattern has come back? One thing I can think of is the [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom.

Comment: @rwong I was in the middle of writing an answer describing the idiom, but you managed with an excellent link. I was only half-jesting in my comment: you rename, find errors to convert/fix code, and rename back. Poor man's refactoring tool, which I've used once.

Comment: @Dysaster: actually, SO encourages you to go ahead and write out a description of the idiom, because in this way your will be presenting information in the most useful form to the asker. Wikipedia's content is not tailored to an asker's particular situation, and contents on external links are not always retrievable or permanent.

Comment: You are asking for C++ private members?

Comment: @Bo Well sort of. In C++ this would be easy.

Comment: @rwong Yes, that is the optimal target state, but pretty much unreachable. The code is incredibly awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure no new code accesses structures directly is to not make them available using total encapsulation. This comes at the cost of not being able to use a structure on the stack anymore. You provide a function to allocate the structure, another to free it, and all module functions accept a pointer to the structure. However, the definition of the structure itself is in the C file, and not the header file. Another disadvantage is that you may need to write a lot of functions to manipulate/query the structure.

I will provide snippets from an old code base where I've used this approach. The header contains:

```
#ifndef INC_QUEUE_H
#define INC_QUEUE_H

typedef enum {
    QUE_OK,
    QUE_BAD_PARAM,
    QUE_NO_MEMORY,
    QUE_SYS_ERROR
} QUE_RV;

typedef struct Queue_st Queue_t;

QUE_RV QUE_New(Queue_t **ppQueue);
QUE_RV QUE_Put(Queue_t *pQueue, int priority, void *pData);
QUE_RV QUE_Get(Queue_t *pQueue, int *priority, void **ppData);
void QUE_Free(Queue_t *pQueue);

#endif /* INC_QUEUE_H */
```

The C file defines the structure `Queue_st`, and implementations of the functions (heavily modified to highlight the approach):

```
#include "queue.h"
#include "log.h"

#define QUE_INITIAL_CAPACITY 128

struct Queue_st {
    /* SNIP: structure contents go here */
};

QUE_RV QUE_New(Queue_t **ppQueue)
{
    QUE_RV rv;

    *ppQueue = malloc(sizeof(Queue_t));

    /* SNIP: Check malloc, Initialize the structure here ... */

    return QUE_OK;
}

void QUE_Free(Queue_t *pQueue)
{
    if (pQueue != NULL)
    {
        /* SNIP: Free contents of the structure before the free below... */
        free(pQueue);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to use `typedef struct StructName *StructHandle;`, and replace all the pointers in the API with `StructHandle`. One less `*` to worry about.

---

EDIT: If you want some members visible, and some not, it is also possible with an extension of the above approach. In your header, define:

```
typedef struct StructPriv StructPriv;

typedef struct {
    /* public members go here */

    StructPriv *private;
} Struct;

Struct *STRUCT_Create();
void STRUCT_Free();
```

In the C file, define the private members, and the functions that manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [checkstyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkstyle) or [PMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_%28software%29) with eclipse IDE. In both utility you can configure your own rules.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be these utilities widely used in java developmet but you can use these for CPP as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use previous tools sugessted by me or this is only for C++ and opensource. [Vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/)

You can write your own rule using Tcl.